# Snowflake MFA fails Error sending SMS&#x3a; Insufficient telephony credits.to UK number

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When enrolling for duo through snowflake for MFA getting an error message Error sending SMS: Insufficient telephony credits.

Is there a limit on free accounts to signup to MFA?
Snowflake is Free trial, Dublin, AWS

Comment: There isn't a limit as far as I know and you're right, MFA is powered by Duo at Snowflake (see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa.html)). You will need to open a case with support for further investigation.